# services.AddDbContext disposing object used in async method before it's used

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Using asp.net core with sqlserver on entity framework core, we have an endpoint for our rest api that we would like to be fire and forget.

in startup, we register the DBContext with the framework

```
services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options=>options.UseSqlServer(/*connection string*/));
```

our controller method is like

```
[HttpPost(/*route*/)]
public ObjectResult doWork([FromBody] string[] args)
{
    IInjectedLogic.doWorkAsync(args);
    return new OkObjectResult("");
}
```

and our logic class is like

```
public interface IInjectedLogic
{
    Task doWorkAsync(string[] args);
}

public class InjectedLogic:IInjectedLogic
{
    private DBContext ctx;
    private ILegacyWCFService wcfClient;
    private ILogger logger;

    public InjectedLogic(DBContext ctx,ILegacyWCFService wcfClient,ILogger logger)
    {
        this.ctx=ctx;
        this.wcfClient=wcfClient;
        this.logger=logger;
    }

    public async Task doWorkAsync(string[] args)
    {
        using(var transaction=ctx.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                string[] processed=await wcfClient.doOtherWorkAsync(args);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.RollBack();
                logger.logError(ex);
            }
            transaction.Commit(); 
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `ctx.Database` is always disposed when begin transaction is called. My hunch is that the framework is calling dispose once the controller finishes and the that's returned goes out of scope.

Can someone confirm my suspicions or tell me what's really going on, and if possible, a way to fix it while still keeping the fire and forget architecture?

Comment: You need to *await* asynchronous methods in order to wait for them to finish, i.e. `await injectedLogic.doWorkAsync(args);`

Comment: the point is I don't <i>want</i> to wait for it to finish before I send the ok response.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new scope from the DI container.  New instances of your dependencies will be resolved and will be disposed when complete.

Example:

```
...
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
...

[HttpPost(/*route*/)]
public IActionResult DoWork([FromBody] string[] args)
{
    using (var scope = Request.HttpContext.RequestServices.CreateScope())
    {
        var worker = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IInjectedLogic>();
        worker.doWorkAsync(args);
    }

    return NoContent();
}
```